# what does MYSQL-entries beginning with sha512:1000: contain?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sequelpro

I'm trying to reset a user-password in a database belonging to a codeigniter application. (though the app might not use standard Codeigniter encryption).

Some of the values have been reseted to an alphanumeric value and some are manually set through the application they begin with "sha512:1000:" I would like to enter a new password. How can I do this? I'm using Sequel Pro

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by hand in the database. The passwords seem to be hashed with the SHA-512 algorithm, but in what way is unclear (usual salts are involved, and that cannot be deducted from the given information). As far as I can see now, the only two ways to get a new password in your database is by reverse engineering the hashing alorithm in the CodeIgniter app and applying it to a new password, or entering it through the application.